# How do you modify Google Chrome browser/user interface?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am trying to find a way to modify the Google Chrome browser.

In Firefox you can use a userChrome.css file, but I now want to do the same thing in Google Chrome. I searched online and it seems that there used to be a way to do this with a custom.css file, but I'm not sure that is what I am looking for and it seems like that is extinct for a while now anyways.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in older chrome versions (at least made sure in chrome <70) a file named Custom.css to customize chrome like userChrome.css which does not exist anymore.

But now in chrome 65+ developer tools support local style sheet overrides: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides

Comment: Great, thanks. From what I could tell, local style sheet overrides can't modify the actual user interface (Chrome browser), right? It's just to override certain pages? In Firefox userChrome.css modifies the actual browser. It was discontinued, but you can re-enable it in about:config. Is there a similar option for Chrome to re-enable custom.css? And will I be able to modify the actual browser UI?

Comment: @TomWilliams no we can't continue custom.css, and you can tweak chrome UI.

Comment: Well... it's a good answer but not quite the answer... that would be to individual pages and I believe the question is also a rant of mine so it's tending more to the simple "No, google screwed you again..."